# How to JSExport a Objective-C Method with Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I want to write a method by the Objective-C that can be exported to JavaScript, so that I can get the JavaScript Object into the native code. For example in the following code: `someObject` is a native implemented object, and fun is its method.

```js
someObject.fun({ k : 'value1', k2 : 'value2'})
```

I know that using `JSExport` can export the native method to JavaScript. and successfully pass the JavaScript String to the native code (`NSString*`). But when I want to pass the JavaScript Object to native, it fails.

How to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the conversion of javascript strings to NSString* as you have already observed, Javascript objects are copied to a KVC-compliant objective-C object (essentially, an NSDictionary instance) before being passed to your objective-c method.

For example, with the following definitions:

```
@protocol MyJSAPI
- (void)fun:(id)param;
@end
@interface MyObject: NSObject<MyJSAPI>
- (void)fun:(id)param;
@end
```

and the initialization of your JSContext as follows:

```
myjscontext[@"someObject"] = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[myjscontext evaluateScript:@"someObject.fun({ k : 'value1', k2 : 'value2'});
```

then your `fun:(id)param` method can access the `k` and `k2` fields of the objects like this:

```
@implementation MyObject
- (void)fun:(id)param {
   NSString* k = [param valueForKey:@"k"];
   NSString* k2 = [param valueForKey:@"k2"];
   NSLog(@"k = %@, k2 = %@", k, k2);
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Sorry, I can not give you an up currently since I am a freshmen here, not enough reputation.

Comment: @RoyMa np, glad you found it helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ste3veh answer.

You can use `JSExportAs` macro in following way to export Objective-C method as JavaScript one:

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject <JSExport>
JSExportAs(fun,
- (void)fun:(id)param
);
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)fun:(id)param {
    NSString* k = [param objectForKey:@"k"];
    NSString* k2 = [param objectForKey:@"k2"];
    NSLog(@"k = %@, k2 = %@", k, k2);
}

@end
```

In this case `param` would be implicitly converted to corresponding Objective-C oblect, using `-[JSValue toObject]`. In your case it will be converted in `NSDictionary`. To avoid implicit conversion, you may specify parameter as `JSValue`:

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject <JSExport>
JSExportAs(fun,
- (void)fun:(JSValue*)param
);
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)fun:(JSValue*)param {
    NSString* k = [[param valueForProperty:@"k"] toString];
    NSString* k2 = [[param valueForProperty:@"k2"] toString];
    NSLog(@"k = %@, k2 = %@", k, k2);
}

@end
```

Note that big JavaScript objects, i.e. `window` or `document`, are very expensive to convert into corresponding Objective-C ones, so second way is preferred. Also, you can use `JSValue` parameter to call back JavaScript methods of this object from Objective-C, using `callWithArguments:`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can. See the `JSExport.h` header: It defines what the arguments can be, and it doesn't appear that generic JavaScript objects can be passed.